# Angular 2 passing Model class to my child component using parent component

Tags: angular

I have been exploring angular 2 from some time and now am running out while implementing this thing.
I have a child component

```
@Component({
   selector: 'child'
})
class child<T> {}
```

Now i want my parent class to pass generic type for my child component dynamically using selector or something in parent.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'parent',
   template: `<child></child>`
})
class parent {}
```

Please let me know if this can be achieved or not. Sorry if am asking silly question

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Define the constructor in the child class that takes an argument of some generic type, e.g. ProductService.

In your parent component define a provider for ProductService using a factory function, which will check some flag variable and will pass to the child a corresponding concrete implementation of the ProductService.

You can read about using factories here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html